# Dynamic Filter based on SESSION_USER

Tags: sql, dremel

I have a table with rows that includes usernames. I have two users who will view the table and I want to filter the table to show specific usernames based on who the session_user is. Is this possible?

Sample Data

```
Username| 
---------
 1      |
 2      | 
 3      | 
 4      |
 5      |
 6      |
```

If session_user() = 'A', table should only show

```
Username| 
---
 1|
 2| 
 3|
```

If session_user() = 'B', table should only show

```
Username| 
---
 4|
 5| 
 6|
```

Additional condition: Aside from the 2 viewers, all usernames will be added as viewer but will be filtered as well only for their own data.

So basically, if the viewer is one of the usernames then it will only show their own data but if it is one of the managers, table will show usernames  that's been assigned to them.

Comment: Do you simply want something like `where session_user = usercolumn`

Comment: Lets say I have rows 1,2,3,4,5,6. Then I have session_user A and B. When session_user = A then only rows 1,2,3 will show but when session_user = B, only rows 4,5,6 will show. I'm just not sure how I can do this in 'Where' clause.

Comment: Edit the question and add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: I added samples

Comment: I'd add a column user to the table, and store A for row 1, 2 and 3. etc. How else do you know which user the coming row with id 13 belongs to?